# Scrolling in preview pane Lotus Notes 8.53

Tags: email, lotus-notes

After updating design notes mail database from 8.52 to 8.53 notes emails don't scroll in document preview even scroll bar is visible, maildoc is "long" enough. The same mails in an database with 8.52 design srcolling. In designer I can not find a difference between framesets for mail views and preview either versions. I can change this reaction when I switched off the embedded browser for mime mail, only then I can't in no notes mails change for show/not show images. How I can control scrolling for notes mails? How it works? Notes client version is 8.53 FP6.

Comment: hi- was it just the mail template that was updated ? not the client as well ?

Comment: Hallo, the client earlier was updatet, when we at all have startet update from 6.55, a year before, now want update mail design to the same level like client, last update was to FP6 some weeks before, the scrolling effect appers straight after mail update.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to compact the workspace or remove the cache.dsk file?

Comment: I don't know why, the effect is on all test installations 50 pcs.